# Cannot find entry module in webpack using nodejs API

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am trying to run webpack from within nodejs. My directory structure looks like this:

```
build
|- dev.js
dist
|- bundle.js
src
|- layout
   |- App.js
|- server
   |- app.js
```

dev.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

// returns a Compiler instance
const compiler = webpack(
  {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    entry: [
      './server/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
);

compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Err');
  }
});
```

app.js:

```
import express from 'express';

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import App from '../layout/App';
const app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(renderToString(<App />));
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
});
```

If I now run `node build/dev.js` it generates my bundle.js, but it does not find my entry module.

```
(function webpackMissingModule() { throw new Error("Cannot find module \"./server/app.js\""); }());
```

Even though I think this is how the entry point should be defined, I have tried many combinations, even the absolute path. But always the same result, it cannot find the entry module. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It looks like something is going wrong with bundling the assets - since webpack looks in your `node_modules` to find its assets it, would be best if you could post your package.json alongside the other files.
2. You're using webpack programatically instead of the default `webpack` command, which normally gives a lot of debug output (along with information about the build-steps, errors, etc.) - I would suggest using that to debug it, and then switch to the programmatical approach when you know that everything is working.
3. It looks like you want to do server-side rendering with react. Some special configuration is needed for your webpack configuration then. This is already handled here: http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

Without having the `package.json` it is really hard to debug exactly what goes wrong here.

Assuming your package.json is correct, here's a `dev.js` file that would work with the above code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

// returns a Compiler instance
const compiler = webpack(
  {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
    target: 'node',
    entry: [
      './server/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
        }
      ]
    },
    externals: nodeModules
  }
);

compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
  console.log(err, stats);
});
```

Comment: It seems that it could not compile <App /> in app.js without having the babel-loader. `npm i --save-dev babel-loader` fixed the issue.

Comment: A small caveat: with private orgs, the packages are installed under node_modules/@organisation/packageName so you must  add them "manually" right after readdirSync. With `nodeModules['@myorg/mypackage'] = 'commonjs mypackage'